# Choosing a string variable in an array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am struggling to get my head around picking out a group of string variables out of an array.

**Code:**

The items in the array:

```
pizzas_with_prices = [("Hawaiian", 8.5), ("Veg Deluxe", 8.5), ("Ham and Cheese", 8.5),("Super Supreme", 8.5), ("Seafood Deluxe", 8.5),("Meatlovers", 11.5), ("Hot 'n' Spicy", 11.5), ("BBQ Chicken and Bacon", 11.5),("Satay Chicken", 11.5)]
```

Selecting the pizzas in the array:

```
for n in range(numPizza):
    pizza = pizza + [int(input("Choose a pizza: "))]
```

For total price of the pizzas selected:

```
for selected in pizza:
    total_price += pizzas_with_prices[selected][1]
    print("$%s" % (total_price))
```

I am having trouble with getting the names of the pizzas selected in the array but I can get the total prices of the pizzas selected. 
Thanks for any of the help!

Edit:

Whole Code:

```
pizzas_with_prices = [("Hawaiian", 8.5), ("Veg Deluxe", 8.5), ("Ham and Cheese", 8.5),
                  ("Super Supreme", 8.5), ("Seafood Deluxe", 8.5),
                  ("Meatlovers", 11.5), ("Hot 'n' Spicy", 11.5), ("BBQ Chicken and Bacon", 11.5),
                  ("Satay Chicken", 11.5)]

def menu():
print("Delivery or Pickup?")
print()
print("1] Delivery ($5 charge)")
print("2] Pickup")
print()

option = int(input(">>"))
if option < 1 or option > 2:
    print("Only 1 or 2")
print()

if option == 1:
    customerName = input("Enter customers name: ")
    customerAddress = input("Enter customer Address: ")
    customerPhone = input("Enter your phone number: ")
    print()
    print("Thank you", customerName, "Customers Address is", customerAddress, "and customers phone number is", customerPhone)
    print()
    orderPizza()

if option == 2:
    customerName = input("Enter customers name: ")
    print()
    orderPizza()

def orderPizza():
numPizza=0
global pizzas_with_prices
Flag = True 
while Flag:
    try:
        numPizza= int(input("How many Pizzas do you want? (MAX 7): "))
        if numPizza ==0 or numPizza > 7:
            print("Not a correct choice, Try again")
        else:
            Flag = False 
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number, Try again")

print()
for index, pizza in enumerate(pizzas_with_prices):
    print("%d %s: $%s" % (index, pizza[0], pizza[1]))
    pizza=[] 

for n in range(numPizza): #covers values from 0 to 9 
    pizza = pizza + [int(input("Choose a pizza: "))] 
    print(pizza)
total_price = 0
for selected in pizza:
    total_price += pizzas_with_prices[selected][1]
    print("$%s" % (total_price))

menu()
```

Comment: What language are you using (it's not Java or C/C++) ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention Python will change title thanks

Comment: `pizzas_with_prices[selected][0]`  is not printing it ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Your example code does not attempt to retrieve the pizza label strings, but that's the part you say you're having trouble with. What have you tried, and what's not working as you expect?

Comment: Where did you get the `[0]` bit

Comment: Most languages start their arrays at index `0`. Thus `0` would be the name of the pizza if `1` is the price.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the section I have already done a menu for the pizzas which output as a list. Using `[0]` I need to get the selected choices of pizzas (integers)  and grab the numbers from the `pizza_with_prices` list eg If selected 1 as the choice of pizza it would grab from the array Veg Deluxe as the name and print out the price of the pizza that was ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the variable pizza must be a list not an integer. Not sure if you haven't indicated it in the snippet above or if its a error. But this should work -

```
pizzas_with_prices = [("Hawaiian", 8.5), ("Veg Deluxe", 8.5), ("Ham and Cheese", 8.5),("Super Supreme", 8.5), ("Seafood Deluxe", 8.5),("Meatlovers", 11.5), ("Hot 'n' Spicy", 11.5), ("BBQ Chicken and Bacon", 11.5),("Satay Chicken", 11.5)]
selected_pizzas = []
for n in range(len(pizzas_with_prices)):
    pizza = int(input("Choose a Pizza:"))
    selected_pizzas.append(pizza)

pizza_price=0.0
for n in selected_pizzas:
    pizza_price += pizzas_with_prices[n][1]
```

Isn't this what you're looking for ?

In your new code all that's missing is:

```
total_price = 0
for selected in pizza:
    total_price += pizzas_with_prices[selected][1]
    **print("%s" % (pizzas_with_prices[selected][0]))**
    print("$%s" % (total_price))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better IMO to use a dictionary for prices, so you don't have to loop to the whole list for the price. Then use the sum function:

```
pizzas_with_prices = {'pizza1': 10, 'pizza2': 15}
selected_pizzas = []
# create the list of selected_pizzas with your code
# eg: selected_pizzas = ['pizza1', 'pizza2', 'pizza1']
pizza_price = sum(pizzas_with_prices[pizza] for pizza in pizza_list)
```